# Nginx returns HTTP Status 200 instead 302 on a proxy_pass configuration

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I have the following configuration on a NGINX which is serving as a reverse proxy to my Docker machine located at: 192.168.99.100:3150.

Basically, I need to hit: http://localhost:8150 and the content displayed has to be the content from inside the Docker.

The configuration bellow is doing his job.

The point here is that when hitting the localhost:8150 I'm getting http status code 302, and I would like to get the http status code 200.

Does anyone know if it's possible to be done on Nginx or any other way to do that?

```
  server {
      listen 8150;

      location / {
          proxy_pass         http://192.168.99.100:3150;
      }
  }
```

Response from a request to http://localhost:8150/products

```
HTTP Requests
-------------

GET /projects                  302 Found
```

Comment: You get what your docker sent to you. It's unclear what do you want to get and why.

Comment: Hey Alexey! The scenario is this one: I want to expose my local machine to the world for free. An awesome tool is ngrok. Since version 2 the feature to attach/bind to a different IP address should be done paying for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

Looks that a simple proxy_pass doens't work quite fine with ngrok.

I'm using proxy_pass with upstream and it's working fine.

Bellow my configuration.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;


    upstream rorweb {
      server                    192.168.99.100:3150 fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
      listen                    8150;
      server_name               git.example.com;
      server_tokens             off;
      root                      /dev/null;

      client_max_body_size      20m;

      location / {
        proxy_read_timeout      300;
        proxy_connect_timeout   300;
        proxy_redirect          off;

        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN;

        proxy_pass              http://rorweb;
      }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

My environment is like this:

- Docker (running a rails project on port 3150)
- Nginx (as a reverse proxy exposing the port 8150)
- Ngrok (exporting my localhost/nginx)